# Generating/downloading a csv in ie9

Tags: javascript, csv, internet-explorer-9, export-to-csv

So, I'm trying to dynamically create and download a csv in IE 9 , using just javascript.

Currently, I use something like this:

```
var oWin = window.open("about:blank", "_blank");
oWin.document.write(csvData);
oWin.document.close();
var success = oWin.document.execCommand('SaveAs', true, 'MyDownload.csv');
oWin.close();
```

Unfortunately, if the system setting of 'hide extensions of known file types' in the file browser is checked, the extension doesn't appear in the download box, so it shows as MyDownload instead of MyDownload.csv and doesn't open correctly.

Does anyone know a better way to go about this?

Comment: This was the only way I could get it to download the CSV file in IE9.  Thanks for that!  I also don't know of any way to get around the OS level setting for hiding extensions.  There probably isn't a way around it other than manually setting that system setting.